# Always On Availability Groups connection with secondary database established for primary database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I'm seeing this messages almost everyday in one of the production server. I don't feel comfortable seeing this..is there anything we can do to suppress this messages ? though it's showing No user action is required.

> Always On Availability Groups connection with secondary database established for primary database 'xxxxx' on the availability replica 'yyyyy' with Replica ID: {xyz}. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

SQL Server Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2)

Thank you in advance...

Comment: you are seeing "connection established", how about "disconnected" messages before it establishes connection back, do you see any of them ?

Comment: Idon't see any disconnected messages, but i see the below messages prior to "connection established" .

*A connection timeout has occurred on a previously established connection to availability replica 'xx' with id [xyz].  Either a networking or a firewall issue exists or the availability replica has transitioned to the resolving role*

*A connection for availability group 'xxx' from availability replica 'xxx' with id  [abc] to 'yyy' with id [abc] has been successfully established.  This is an informational message only. No user action is required*

Comment: Is the secondary replica on the same subnet? Do you see any errors on the secondary replica?

Comment: Yes, both nodes are in same subnet and no messages in the secondary replica.

Comment: Maybe you have some network latency? Have you tried to increase Session Timeout in AG properties?

Comment: That's the last think i want to to do, what's the recommended  Session Timeout value? currently it's 10sec.
Onemore thing is Availability Mode is *Synchronous commit* on both nodes.

Comment: To Marcin's point, what does a simple Ping test show from one server to the other and visa versa? (I'd run it a couple times on each end to see the average.) Though yes, 10s of ping time between two servers on the same subnet nonetheless, is extreme.

Comment: from primary..
Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 38ms, Average = 11ms

Comment: from secondary..Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 60ms, Average = 17ms

Comment: Check this article: https://www.sqlshack.com/session-timeouts-in-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups/ in one of our systems we have session time out set to 120 and this was recommended by MS. But it might depend on environment.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm seeing this messages almost everyday in one of the production server. I don't feel comfortable seeing this..is there anything we can do to suppress this messages ?

These are informational messages and you want them in your logs so that it's possible to correlate events and issues. There is no way to turn them off.

There are various underlying causes for this to occur ranging from actual network issues, to drivers, overloaded schedulers, etc., and it's not going to be possible to know from just from the message- hence why you want these in the logs.

If you're worried about this then I'd attempt to get to the root of the problem, otherwise just live with the messages.